# Why Do If/Else Spacebars Tags Not Work?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Hey for some reason this if/else statement in my template is not working:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="custom-search-input">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
          {{#if addingSubreddit}}
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2%;">
              <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="addSubreddit" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
              </button>
          {{else}}
            <button id="newSubreddit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            </button>
          {{/if}}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It gives me this error:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client/views/subreddits.html:14: Unexpected {{else}}
...n>           {{else}}           hey      ...
                        ^

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

You have placed span tag wrong. you have coded the {{#if}} outside the span tag but coded the {{else}} inside the  tag which is wrong.

instead this might solve the problem:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="custom-search-input">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
      {{#if addingSubreddit}}
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2%;">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="addSubreddit" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      {{else}}
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2%;">
          <button id="newSubreddit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. Im used to working with haml so im always forgetting about closed tags!

Answer (score 1):

You can't let tags unclosed inside block helpers, so you have to rewrite your template code like this :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="custom-search-input">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
          {{#if addingSubreddit}}
            <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text">
          {{/if}}
          <span class="input-group-btn" style="width: 2%;">
            {{#if addingSubreddit}}
              <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="addSubreddit" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
              </button>
            {{else}}
              <button id="newSubreddit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
              </button>
            {{/if}}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```